# Android animation spinning wheel with clickable circles

Tags: android, animation

I was looking for animation which is like a spinning wheel which has circles and they are clickable. So two Actions one is Touch and fling to rotate the wheel second to click the circle. Circle values need to be dynamically assigned. 
  Please have a look at attached  [Click to view the sample image to help you visualize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inPr5.jpg)

Comment: `"I was looking for animation which..."` and what have you done so far (besides "looking for") ?

Comment: Please edit your question , there is screen shot .